# Old anime with isekai and gems / crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

It's an old anime, from maybe 2008 or earlier.

The best part I can remember is that the main character is fleeing or something in the first episode, so he stop on a bridge, with nowhere to escape, but then he got teleported to another world.
In this world, they use gems / crystals which contain monsters, and absorb their powers to fight.

This guy has a monstrous, rare, epic gem / crystal, which in legend couldn't be controlled or something. If I remember, he's yellow and looked like [Greymon](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Greymon) from *Digimon*.
If I remember well, there's an episode where the main character fights in an arena, which reminded me of that arena city in *Kino no Tabi*.

It's not *Deltora Quest*.

Comment: My first impulse is *Magi-Nation*, but that doesn't fit with the yellow monster. Was the summoned creature an animal? Humanoid? Old Testament angel?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the Chinese anime [Zinba](https://syncogon.tumblr.com/post/160753306961/some-chinese-cartoons) (神魄)?

> Kan is happily chatting with his closest friend on an ordinary school day when, all of a sudden, he finds himself pulled into an alternate fantasy world. This world is filled with Zinba, large and powerful creatures that may form bonds with select humans, called Linkers, for immense battle power. After becoming a Linker with one of the strongest Zinba ever to exist, Kan joins the peacekeeping Dux force of the kingdom of Toria and fights against the various evils threatening the land, all while trying to find his way back to his own world.

Zan’s Zinba is a yellow lion that is associated with a red gem. It has two forms, one of which is like a small toy that sits on his shoulder:

[image: title art showing main characters]

Comment: If accepted, this would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207382/anime-about-a-red-haired-boy-suddenly-being-transported-into-another-world/217343#217343 (noting for the purpose of linking it).